# Is there any way to open a login shell from a shell script file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

My script is called from a shell prompt. Is there any way to ignore the immediate parent shell's properties.

After I loging to my box. I run command like (say script1.sh), script1.sh sets the current environment to be used in the script1 context.

I have creates a script ( say script2.sh ). I am planning to add some of the command in this script does not work in the context of script1.sh ( these command works before executing script1.sh).

Is there any way in which I can call some command in script2.sh which is not called in the context of script1.sh instead those commands should be called in new shell in the same condition as my login shell.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show the code you have, what you expect it to do, and what you want it to do. That will make it much easier to answer.

Comment: Do you mean: export a=1 in script1.sh, and then script1.sh runs script2.sh, but you don't want script2.sh has a=1.

Comment: You'll need to put some more detail, which of those scripts are environment setting scripts ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can use:

```
unset a
```

However, it is not very convenient, because it requires to unset one-by-one.
Looking forward to better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its now only about environment variables. 
When I execute script1.sh ( from my login shell) it opens up a new shell.

I want to achieve below manual commands in a single script on the current shell prompt assuming both script2.sh and script3.sh are available in PATH of my login shell:

1. script2.sh
2. exit  # this will take me back to the login shell. Executing script3.sh from here is fine.
3. script3.sh

Now script3.sh is execute from my login shell and it works fine.

Is there any way to club the manual operations into a shell script?